# What is the minimum recommended number of rounds for Argon2?

Tags: password-hashing, argon2

I'm hashing passwords with argon2 using Python's passlib library and am wondering how many rounds I should use to future proof security. The default uses 2 rounds but I'm wondering if it'd be sensible to increase this. The documentation doesn't make any specific recommendations.

Comment: Use as much as you can. You should use as much as is possible in your environment. Thats why there is no minimum defined - if you want minimum overhead then don't use argon2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR: Yes, you probably should increase this, even though not by that much.**

First, we need to identify the Argon2 variant in-use [which is Argon2i for Passlib](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/lib/passlib.hash.argon2.html).

Now if we take a look at [section 5.7 of the Argon2 specification](https://github.com/P-H-C/phc-winner-argon2/blob/master/argon2-specs.pdf), we will learn that there are some special attacks if only 1 or 2 rounds are used which is why you want the round value to be larger than that. [Some might recommend to use something like 10 rounds](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/40000/23623).

In practice, [I'd recommend following the same methodology as I laid out for Argon2d](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/43391/23623): Find out how much memory you can use, pick a lower bound for the round count (eg something like 5?) and then maximize memory usage within your time limit and perhaps *tweak* the time with the round number.